# Tensorflow not finding CUDNN

Tags: python3, cuda, gpu

Hey all I have installed:

- CUDA 8.0
- cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v5.1
- Tensorflow (gpu version)

I installed then copied cudnn as suggested on tensorflow website:

```
rik@rik-MS-7971:~/Downloads$ sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
[sudo] password for rik: 
rik@rik-MS-7971:~/Downloads$ sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
rik@rik-MS-7971:~/Downloads$ sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

And thses files reside in the /usr/local/cuda-8.0 folder since that is the version I have, and /usr/local/cuda is a link to this folder.

But I get the error below when I run sess.run(). Where do I put the files to get this working properly? Thanks.

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:102] **Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:2259] Unable to load cuDNN DSO**
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:102] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.797
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.45GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:126] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:136] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:838] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could run your program through strace to see which files it tries to open , this should show you where its trying to find the file.

-f means keep tracing into forked parts of the program

-e open   means only show 'open' syscalls , it would be too verbose otherwise.

```
strace -f -e open /path/to/your/program
```

Comment: Thanks I was able to see where other files were and put them there (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu)

Comment: Do you know what this error means? strace: exec: Exec format error